# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined in console

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I am trying to append a div when a checkbox is selected in dajngo template but i keep receiving `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` in the console

the template:

```
{% extends 'base_layout.html'%}
{%load static%}
{% block content %}
<div class="inventory-content">
    <div class='category'>
        <div>Categories</div>
        <div class='category-checkbox'>
            {%for category in categories%}
            <input type="checkbox" id="{{category.id}}" name="{{category.name}}" value="{{category.id}}">
            <label for="{{category.name}}"> {{category.name}}</label><br>
            {%endfor%}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='items'></div>

</div>    

<script>
    $('.category-checkbox input[type="checkbox"]').click(function (){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
             // Add the element to the div with an id identifier
             $('.items').append('<div id="[{{category.id}}]">123</div>');
        } else {
             // Remove the element from the div targeted by the id identifier
             $('.items #[{{category.id}}]').remove();
        }
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery in django is [aliased to django.jQuery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#jquery) instead of $.  If you want to use $ instead, you can do something like this:

```
(function($) {
    //do some stuff with $ here

})(django.jQuery);
```